# Публикация изображения в соц.сети

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Доброго времени суток.

Есть галерея изображений,
задача: сделать возможность расшаривания изображения в соц.сети

На примере VK пробовал таким образом
href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=URL&amp;title=TITLE&amp;image=IMAGE&amp;noparse=true"

но get параметры не подтягиваються.

Ребят, кто какие решения использовал для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Виджет «[Мне нравится](https://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=%C4%EE%EA%F3%EC%E5%ED%F2%E0%F6%E8%FF+%EA+%E2%E8%E4%E6%E5%F2%F3+%CC%ED%E5+%ED%F0%E0%E2%E8%F2%F1%FF)» и правильно прописанные meta-теги для страницы каждого изображения.